# include page within page, but on LOCAL website

Tags: include, local

So this is fun. I've been tasked with building a website thats going to not only be hosted, but also sent around on USB keys to various clients. I was planning on using PHP and INCLUDES for the menu and such, but clearly that won't work on some random persons local machine. I thought SHTML too, but that won't work either.

I've tried searching google relentlessly, but I think I might be plugging in the wrong terms because I've found 0 results.

Can anyone make a suggestion that would allow includes to work locally off a USB key? Or at least something similar...

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform your includes before you publish the files. Generate static HTML from templates at build time, not run time.

You can use tools such as [ttree](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/tools/ttree.html) for this.

Comment: Great idea! Thanks very much for the help. I never would have thought of something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the other machines don't have a local server environment and thats why you cant use PHP. You could use javascript to include other files. A jquery example would be

```
$.get('file.html').done(function (html) { 
    $('body').append(html); 
});
```

Comment: Yeah the main problem is that I have ZERO control over who will receive this site, and how they will get it. They could get it through the domain, or on a USB key, on a CD...its variables are huge. 

Will using Javascript like that append the file to the spot that the code occurs, like with PHP? Or will it tack it on the end of the page? 

Thanks much for the help!

Comment: Many browsers will refuse to load content from local filesystems using XHR. This isn't going to be a practical solution.